Is it possible to fail a build if .NET 8 project references a Windows specific library?
I migrated a large code base to .NET8 that was previously running on Windows. Now it has to run on Linux. I would like for build process to fail if there is an Windows specific library that will not work on Linux.
I tried adding System.Drawing.Common and build was successful on Linux. It failed in the runtime when I called the library and that is a huge issue for me. Is there any configuration that can help me with this? Or maybe some free tool that could scan a project and list these libraries?

There's not much detail here.  Can you provide a [MCVE]?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/platform-compat-analyzer maybe?

I figured it out. In the .csproj file I added:
    <ItemGroup>
        <SupportedPlatform Include="Linux" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <WarningsAsErrors>CA1416</WarningsAsErrors>
    </PropertyGroup>

CA1416 throws this warning if you have usage of incompatible library:

This call site is reachable on all platforms.

By using the WarningsAsErrors we can set that warning to be an error and that will cause build to fail.
